# anaconda 3 directory remains after uninstall

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, anaconda3

***EDIT***

Please note I deleted `ANACONDA3\envs` and `ANACONDA3\pkgs` as per anaconda docs linked in main answer.  Contents of Anaconda directory:

```
C:\Users\u03132tk>cd C:\ANACONDA3

C:\ANACONDA3>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0C73-2057

 Directory of C:\ANACONDA3

15/06/2023  11:23    <DIR>          .
15/06/2023  11:23    <DIR>          ..
15/06/2023  11:12    <DIR>          conda-meta
15/06/2023  11:09    <DIR>          DLLs
15/06/2023  11:12    <DIR>          etc
15/06/2023  11:12    <DIR>          include
15/06/2023  11:09    <DIR>          Lib
15/06/2023  11:12    <DIR>          Library
15/06/2023  11:12    <DIR>          libs
08/09/2020  18:10            27,936 msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll
08/03/2023  18:51         4,490,240 python39.dll
08/03/2023  18:51        13,668,352 python39.pdb
15/06/2023  11:12    <DIR>          Scripts
24/05/2023  13:51    <DIR>          share
15/06/2023  11:23    <DIR>          tcl
24/05/2023  13:10    <DIR>          Tools
08/09/2020  18:10            44,328 vcruntime140_1.dll
08/03/2023  18:40           524,800 venvlauncher.exe
08/03/2023  18:40           524,288 venvwlauncher.exe
24/10/2022  15:04            87,552 zlib.dll
               7 File(s)     19,367,496 bytes
              13 Dir(s)  14,452,559,872 bytes free
```

***Original message:***

After having dependency issues, I decided to delete and re-install anaconda3.  I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/) (full uninstall --> simple remove - I am on Windows 10).  In add or remove programs, I uninstalled both anaconda 3 and then Python 3 (I had installed python 3 externally to conda - I now know this was a terrible idea).  I also uninstalled Python Launcher.  I now want to re-install anaconda 3, but the anaconda 3 directory is still on my computer (`C:\ANACONDA3` - it is 1.62 GB).

I am not sure why it was not removed - is it safe to simply delete it?  I suspect that having two copies of Anaconda3 hanging around would be even worse than having multiple Python versions, so would like to be sure before I do anything.

Thanks!
Tim

Comment: What exactly is inside the directory?

Comment: Hello again FlyingTeller, thanks for your help!  I have edited the question with the first level of files/folders in the ANACONDA3 directory, please let me know if there is any other information that would be useful.

Comment: Silly question: have you rebooted after the uninstall - anaconda usually schedules to delete the folder during the nextreboot? Otherwise, if all steps from the docs (simple install and full uninstall) ran without issue, then I would say that it is safe to just delete this folder.

Comment: Just tried and it is still there :( OK perfect, thanks very much!  As long as the reinstall works that is the main thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `ANACONDA3` folder is generally safe as conda installs isolated environments to your system

To ensure `conda` is completely removed from your system, you will need to make sure its removed from your `PATH` environment variables

To do so, follow these steps:

1. right-click on the **Computer** or **This PC** icon on the desktop and select **Properties**
2. **Advanced system settings** link which should appear on the left-hand side.
3. **System Properties** > **Advanced** > **Environment Variables**
   [image]
4. Delete any `conda` related `Variable:Value` pair

If OP still runs into issue with `anaconda` installation, you can choose to install a minimal version via [MiniForge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) for the community version replacement of `Anaconda`, the minimal installer skips packages which come with `Anaconda`.

After installation, run:

`conda create -n firstEnv python=3.11 ipython` to install python 3.11

- replace firstEnv with your environment name and 3.11 to desired python version

And install necessary packages via `pip install` and `conda install`

Happy coding!

Comment: What do you mean by "which sorts things out for you.". In the scope of your answer and the question, it sounds like it would somehow assist with anaconda uninstall, which is very misleading. The recommendation to install miniforge seems to be very unrelated to the problem

Comment: @FlyingTeller i have modified to post. my intention was to provide a solution for OP if he/she runs into issue installing `Anaconda`. Installing a minimal version of `conda` will potentially skip lots of unnecessary packages and it adds `conda` to PATH by default whereas `Anaconda` does not

Comment: `it adds conda to PATH by default whereas Anaconda does not` this is incorrect. Just like anaconda, it provides the option, but with a `NOT recommended` right underneath the checkbox. By default it is of course unchecked

Comment: What you said might be true using the Windows installer, however, I installed `conda` via bash script from `miniforge` repo, which adds `conda` to PATH by default

Comment: Hi zwjjoy thanks for the help - I cant see any env variables with conda, so looks like it is OK!  I have heard of the smaller conda flavours but think I will stick with vanilla conda for now.  Thanks to you both for your help!